# Output JCoTable rows using EL <C:forEach>

Tags: java, el, jco, sapjco3

I have created a java webapp that reads a custom table (consisting of 13 fields per record) from a SAP backend into a JCoTable in the webapp and this all works fine.

My requirement is to output all the records on the JCoTable onto a JSP using EL. How do I reference each individual field for output purposes? i.e.

```
<c:forEach items="${claimstable}" var="clms">
      ${clms.field1}
      ${clms.field2}
      ${clms.field3}  
</c:forEach>
```

I have tried using an ArrayList, TreeSet and HashMap to output the table contents on the JSP, using a servlet to forward on the request attribute to the JSP, but I cannot directly access each field, I can only output the contents as one long string.

Do I need to create a class of my table fieldnames and proceed that way? Or what?

Any and all help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I went with was to create an object of my custom table with setters and getters create each field as a property within the object i.e.

```
public class ClaimTableProperties {


private String zuonr;
private String bktxt;
private String blart;
private String belnr; 
...etc.
```

and then map each row of the JCoTable per field to an arraylist:

```
static ArrayList<ClaimTableProperties> claimstable = new ArrayList<ClaimTableProperties>();

    JCoTable claims = function.getTableParameterList().getTable("CLAIM_DETAILS");

    claims.firstRow();
    int rownums = claims.getNumRows();
    ClaimTableProperties[] ctp = new ClaimTableProperties[rownums];

    for (int i = 0; i < rownums; i++) {
            ctp[i] = new ClaimTableProperties();
            ctp[i].setBelnr(claims.getString("BELNR"));
            ctp[i].setBktxt(claims.getString("BKTXT"));
            ctp[i].setZuonr(claims.getString("ZUONR"));
            ctp[i].setBlart(claims.getString("BLART")); 
            claimstable.add(ctp[i]);
            claims.nextRow(); 
    } // End for
```

In your servlet, set the attribute so it's known to your jsp

```
ArrayList<ClaimTableProperties> claims = dgc.returnClaimsTable();
request.setAttribute("claimstable", claims);
```

Then on the jsp, use JSTL to output each required field:

```
<table>
<c:forEach items="${claimstable}" var="claim">
<tr>
<td>${claim.belnr}</td>
<td>${claim.bktxt}</td>
<td>${claim.zuonr}</td>
<td>${claim.blart}</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

First set the values in the request and then try to access it in the jsp

Do it in your servlet

```
List<List<Person>> claimstable= getItSomehow();
request.setAttribute("claimstable", claimstable);
```

The claimstable will be accessible in the jsp.
Use double for each loop to traverse the individual String

Comment: I have tried creating an ArrayList<String> in my servlet and sending it to my jsp via request.setAttribute but I cannot access each individual field. Should i create an ArrayList<customtable> ?

Comment: Are you forwarding your servlet to the write jsp?
Please share your servlet.

Comment: I can access the "claimstable" in my jsp (similar to how you've set it out above) but only as a continuous string because I've set it as an ArrayList<String>, however I need to access each individual field that makes up the table

Comment: You need to use it as a 2-Dimensional Matrix., i.e. List of List of Strings as
`List<List<String>>` and set your entries into the Object according to your requirements.